# BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283:

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

The below one is my controller code from AdminController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Session;
    use Redirect;
    use Response;
    use App\KGB;

    class AdminController extends Controller
    {
        public function add_kgb()
        {
            $kgb_type = Input::get('kgb_type');
            $kgb_price = Input::get('kgb_price');
            $region_id = Input::get('region_id');
            $brand_id = Input::get('brand_id');
            $count = KGB::count();
            $kgb_id = "KGB".sprintf("%05d", ($count+1));

            $add_kgb = new KGB;
            $add_kgb->kgb_id = $kgb_id;
            $add_kgb->kgb_type = $kgb_type;
            $add_kgb->kgb_price = $kgb_price;
            $add_kgb->region_id = $region_id;
            $add_kgb->brand_id = $brand_id;
            $add_kgb->flag = '1';
            $add_kgb->save();
            Session::flash('kgb_success','Successfully Added KG Billing!');
            return Redirect::to('kgb');
        }

        public function edit_kgb()
        {
            $kgb_type = Input::get('kgb_type');
            $kgb_price = Input::get('kgb_price');
            $region_id = Input::get('region_id');
            $brand_id = Input::get('brand_id');
            $kgb_id = Input::get('kgb_id');

            KGB::where('kgb_id', $kgb_id)->update(array('kgb_type' => $kgb_type, 'kgb_price' => $kgb_price, 'region_id' => $region_id, 'brand_id' => $brand_id));

            Session::flash('kgb_success_edit','Successfully Edited KG Billing!');
            return Redirect::to('kgb');
        }

        public function kgb_status($id)
        {
            $status = KGB::where('id',$id)->pluck('status');
            if($status=='0')
                KGB::where('id',$id)->update(array('status' => '1'));
            else
                KGB::where('id',$id)->update(array('status' => '0'));

            Session::flash('kgb_success_status','Successfully Edited KG Billing!');
            return Redirect::to('kgb');
        }
    }
```

This is my base controller code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

And this is my route code

```
Route::get('kgb', function () {
    return view('admin.kgb');
});

Route::post('add_kgb', 'AdminController@add_kgb');
Route::post('edit_kgb', 'AdminController@edit_kgb');
Route::get('kgb_status/{id}', 'AdminController@kgb_status');
```

this one is my model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class KGB extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'kg_billing';
}
```

Till now all my controllers and routes are working but now this method is throwing an error. Please help me out

[This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL7S5.png)

Comment: You need to explain where you think the error is coming from, SO is not a debugging service. Help us help you.

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and show us a screenshot of the result?

Comment: I'm not an expert in laravel, my code just works and this problem on Method [add_kgb] does not exist just pops out of nowhere.

Comment: @TheFallen this is a critical corporate project, i'm listing out only the routes related to the above code

Comment: POST     | add_kgb                 |      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@add_kgb

Comment: If you're running `php artisan serve` stop it, run `php artisan cache:clear` and try again.

Comment: @TheFallen i'm not running 'serve' and i've cleared the cache but same error pops up. Thanks again for ur help, but let me know other options

Comment: The irony here is that the same code is in my live server and it's working over there but not in my local system, all this is happening after I connected and pushed the code to github

Comment: execute `composer dump-autoload` then try again

Comment: @RavishaHesh sorry, no luck

Comment: Did you try to find any solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue with 5.3 version. Cleared all types of cache, still not resolved